# How to implement a recursive MRSW lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

I need a fully-recursive multiple-reader/single-writer lock (shared mutex) for my project - I don't agree with the notion that if you have complete const-correctness you shouldn't need them (there was some discussion about that on the boost mailing list), in my case the lock should protect a completely transparent cache which would be mutable in any case.

As for the semantics of recursive MRSW locks, I think the only ones that make sense are that acquiring a exclusive lock in addition to a shared one temporarily releases the shared one, to be reacquired when the exclusive one is released.

Has the somewhat strange effect that unlocking can wait but I can live with that - writing rarely happens anyway and recursive locking usually only happens through recursive code paths, in which case the caller has to be prepared that the call might wait in any case. To avoid it one can still simply upgrade the lock instead of using recursive locking.

Acquiring a shared lock on top of an exclusive one should obviously just increases the lock count.

So the question becomes - how should I implement it? The usual approach with a critical section and two semaphores doesn't work here because - as far as I can see - the woken up thread has to handshake, by inserting it's thread id into the lock's owner map.

I suppose it would be doable with two condition variables and a couple of mutexes but the sheer amount of synchronization primitives that would end up using sounds like a bit too much overhead for my taste.

An idea which just sprang into my mind is to utilize TLS to remember the type of lock I'm holding (and possibly the local lock counts). Have to think it through - but I'll still post the question for now.

Target platform is Win32 but that shouldn't really matter. Note that I'm specifically  targeting Win2k so anything related to the new MRSW lock primitive in Windows 7 is not relevant for me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I solved it.

It can be done with just 2 semaphores, a critical section and almost no more locking than for a regular non-recursive MRSW lock (there is obviously some more CPU-time spent inside the lock because that multimap must be managed) - but it's **tricky**. The structure I came up with looks like this:

```
// Protects everything that follows, except mWriterThreadId and mRecursiveUpgrade
CRITICAL_SECTION mLock;
// Semaphore to wait on for a read lock
HANDLE mSemaReader;
// Semaphore to wait on for a write lock
HANDLE mSemaWriter;
// Number of threads waiting for a write lock.
int mWriterWaiting;
// Number of times the writer entered the write lock.
int mWriterActive;
// Number of threads inside a read lock. Note that this does not include
// recursive read locks.
int mReaderActiveThreads;
// Whether or not the current writer obtained the lock by a recursive 
// upgrade. Note that this member might be set outside the critical
// section, so it should only be read from by the writer during his
// unlock.
bool mRecursiveUpgrade;
// This member contains the current thread id once for each
// (recursive) read lock held by the current thread in addition to an 
// undefined number of other thread ids which may or may not hold a 
// read lock, even inside the critical section (!).
std::multiset<unsigned long> mReaderActive;
// If there is no writer this member contains 0.
// If the current thread is the writer this member contains his
// thread-id.
// Otherwise it can contain either of them, even inside the 
// critical section (!).
// Also note that it might be set outside the critical section.
unsigned long mWriterThreadId;
```

Now, the basic idea is this:

Full update of `mWriterWaiting` and `mWriterActive` for an unlock is performed by the unlocking thread.

For `mWriterThreadId` and `mReaderActive` this is not possible, as the waiting thread needs to insert itself when it was released.

So the rule is, that you may never access those two members **except** to check whether you are holding a read lock or are the current writer - specifically it may not be used to checker whether or not there are **any** readers / writers - for that you have to use the (somewhat redundant but necessary for this reason) `mReaderActiveThreads` and `mWriterActive`.

I'm currently running some test code (which has been going on deadlock- and crash-free for 30 minutes or so) - when I'm sure that it's stable and I've cleaned up the code somewhat I'll put it on some pastebin and add a link in a comment here (just in case someone else ever needs this).

Comment: Forgot to mention that <code>mReaderActiveThreads</code> is obviously also managed by the unlocking thread.

Comment: Did you ever make your code available anywhere? Would you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some thinking. Starting from the simple "two semaphores and a critical section" one adds a writer lock count and a owning writer TID to the structure.

Unlock still set most of the new status in the critsec. Readers still normally increase the lock count - recursive locking simply adds a non-existing reader to the counter.

During writers lock() I compare the owning TID, and if the writer already own it the write lock counter is increased.

Setting the new writer TID can't be done by the unlock() - it doesn't know which one will be wakened, but if writers reset it back to zero in their unlock() it's not a problem - the current thread id won't ever be zero and setting it is an atomic operation.

All sounds simple enough - one nasty problem left: A recursive reader-reader lock while a writer is waiting will deadlock. And I don't know how to solve that short of doing a reader-biased lock... somehow I need to know whether or not I already own a reader lock.

Using TLS doesn't sound too great after I realized that the number if available slots might be rather limited...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to provide your writer exclusive access to the data, while readers can operate simultaneously (if this is not what you want, please clarify your question).

I think you need to implement a sort of "inverse semaphore", i.e. a semaphore that will block a thread when positive, and signal all waiting threads when zero. If you do this, you can use two such semaphores for your program. The operation of your threads could then be the following:

```
Reader:
(1) wait on sem A
(2) increase sem B
(3) read operation
(4) decrease sem B

Writer:
(1) increase sem A 
(2) wait on sem B
(3) write operation
(4) decrease sem A
```

In this way the writer will perform the write operation as soon as all pending readers have finished reading. As soon as your writer finishes, readers can resume their operation without blocking each other.

I am not familiar with Windows mutex/semaphore facilities but I can think of a way to implement such semaphores using the POSIX threads API (combining a mutex, a counter and a conditional variable).